# How to keep a sprite drawn even after the the condition that drew it is no longer valid?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, draw

The question I have has to do with a specific portion of my code in Pygame where I m trying to draw a new sprite onto the screen every couple of seconds.

```
  def spawn(self):
    self.count += 2
    alien1_sprite = Alien1((rand.randrange(38,462),50))
    rem = self.count % 33
    if rem == 0:
      self.alien1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
      self.alien1.add(alien1_sprite)
      self.alien1.draw(screen)
```

Whenever I call the spawn function no sprites exist at the same time, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Keep a list of aliens in you object like self.aliens = [] and append sprites to the list and loop over them to draw them. When an alien is truly done remove it from the list.

Comment: Can you type out a solution because iḿ having trouble incorporating a list into the program?

Comment: What type/class of object is `self`? Is it a class you defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you create a new *Group* for each alien. You only have to create the *Group* once and add the Alien *Sprites* to this one *Group*:

- Create the `alien1` *Group* in the constructor (**init**) of the class.
- Add the aliens in `spawn` method.
- Draw all the aliens in the *Group* using your "draw" method. (The name of your method may be different - I don't know)

```py
class ...

    def __init__(self):
        # [...]
 
        self.alien1 = pygame.sprite.Group() # creat the group in the constructor

    def spawn(self):
        self.count += 2
        rem = self.count % 33
        if rem == 0:
            alien1_sprite = Alien1((rand.randrange(38,462),50))
            self.alien1.add(alien1_sprite)
      
    def draw(self):    # your draw or render method

       # [...]

       self.alien1.draw(screen)  # draw all the aliens
```

Read the documentation of [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). The *Group* manages the *Sprites* it contains. The *Group* is the "list" that stores the *Sprites*.